# How to choose early / last date in range in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

in range (ws) below I have datetimes. I tried hours to print only early / late date but I couldn't. Like min() , max(), if else.. and etc. It has be very simple way I think, but dont know how. How to solve this headache?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

ws1 = ws['B3':'B7']

for i in ws1:    
    for cell in i:
        print (cell.value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the values of the cells.

```
values = [row[0].value for row in ws['B3:B7']]
print(min(values))
print(max(values))
```

Comment: It gives **Syntax Error**: print (max(values))

`from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'VAT.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

values = [row[0].value for row in ws['B3:B7']
print (min(values))
print (max(values))`

Comment: You should always provide the full traceback but I think I've fixed the example by adding a square bracket at th end of the first line.

Comment: Wow! it works! solution of 2 days headache. Please, can you explain 1 line code?

Comment: See list comprehensions in the Python documentation.